# How to use AAC paging library with list size different than list size returned by Room database

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components, android-paging

I'm trying to use the new `Paging Library` and `Room` as database but I'm facing a problem, the `PagedList` returned by the database is not supposed to be the same list sent to the UI, I `map` some entities before showing it to the user and during this `map` operation I change the list size (add items), apparently the `Paging Library` doesn't support this kind of operation because when I try to run the app I get this exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid Function 'function_name' changed return size. This is not supported.
```

Looking at the paging library source code you see this method:

```
static <A, B> List<B> convert(Function<List<A>, List<B>> function, List<A> source) {
    List<B> dest = function.apply(source);
    if (dest.size() != source.size()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Invalid Function " + function
            + " changed return size. This is not supported.");
    }
    return dest;
}
```

Is there a workaround or something for dealing with when you add dynamic items to the `PagedList` before using it?

This is what I'm doing

DAO

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM table_name")
fun getItems(): DataSource.Factory<Int, Item>
```

LocalSource

```
fun getItems(): DataSource.Factory<Int, Item> {
    return database.dao().getItems()
        .mapByPage { map(it) } // This map operation changes the list size
}
```

Comment: I'm facing problem like yours. If you find any solution for it, please answer your question

Comment: I filed an issue on the Android bug tracker for this. Please star it if this affects you
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142890117

Answer (score 0):

I face same problem and still looking for better solution.
In my case, I have to display **1 section** before each **users load** from API and here is my workaround.

```
class UsersViewModel : ViewModel() {
    var items: LiveData<PagedList<RecyclerItem>>

    init {
        ...
        items = LivePagedListBuilder<Long, RecyclerItem>(
            sourceFactory.mapByPage { it -> mapUsersToRecyclerItem(it) }, config).build()
    }

    private fun mapUsersToRecyclerItem(users: MutableList<User>): List<RecyclerItem> {
        val numberOfSection = 1
        for (i in 0 until numberOfSection) {
            users.add(0, User()) // workaround, add empty user here
        }

        val newList = arrayListOf<RecyclerItem>()
        newList.add(SectionItem())
        for (i in numberOfSection until users.size) {
            val user = users[i]
            newList.add(UserItem(user.login, user.avatarUrl))
        }
        return newList
    }
}
```

My current user class

```
data class User(
    @SerializedName("login")
    val login: String,
    @SerializedName("id")
    val id: Long = 0,
    @SerializedName("avatar_url")
    val avatarUrl: String
) {
    constructor() : this("", 0, "")
}
```

Of course, to display `Section`, I will have another way without add it to `RecyclerView data list` (like using position only) but in my case user can remove item from the list so using position may hard to handle

Actually, I rollbacked to use old load more way (using [EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener](https://www.google.com.vn/search?q=EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener)) but hope it help

Comment: Is your output `newList` gonna same size as initial input `users`? I thought exception will be thrown, if the returned output `newList` isn't same size as input `users`?

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found a solution..

Although it's a workaround it worked for me.

In my case, I was trying to create an alphabet sectioned list for a names like this:

```
**A - HeaderItem**
Aaron - Item
Anny - Item
**B - HeaderItem**
Bob - Item
Bil
**C - HeaderItem**
....
```

The items in ROOM are only the names of course, when I am trying to map the paged items and add the sections headers it change the list size and I am getting the same error.

What I did is, the HeaderItem object wraps an Item like this:

First, all Items are implementing the ListItem interface

```
interface ListItem{
 const val HEADER = 0
 const val ITEM = 1
 fun getItemType() : Int
}
```

Then the header items looks like this

```
class HeaderItem(val headerTitle : String, val item : Item) : ListItem {
  @override
  fun getItemType() : Int {
    return ListItem.HEADER
  }
}
```

Then when I map the items, when adding a HeaderItem, it takes an Item in it, this way the mapped PagedList size doesn't change. Now I am not getting this exception.

However, 
This creates some additional work as I had to set the HeaderItem decoration explicitly and also in the adapter, when bind the header item I had to take care the internal Item + all its logic such as click listeners etc'.

I will be happy if there will be support for changes in the list size out of the box.

Comment: My preferred way doing this, is not adding items, but instead use https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.ItemDecoration.html
So, your HeaderItems are not items of the adapter and don't change the size of the list.