# Paging library : How to transform a PagedList to another PagedList with different size?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-paging

Currently, we have a data structure stored in Room SQLite, named `Todo`

Our current workflow is as follow

1. Dao is returning `DataSource.Factory<Integer, Todo>`
2. Use `LivePagedListBuilder` to turn `DataSource.Factory<Integer, Todo>` into `LiveData<PagedList<Todo>>`
3. Observe `LiveData<PagedList<Todo>>`, and use `submitList` to pass `PagedList<Todo>` to `PagedListAdapter<Todo, TodoAdapter.ViewHolder>`

---

So far so good for such simple use case.

However, right now, we have a more complex UI requirement. We need to transform `Todo` to `TransformedTodo`, before `submitList` to `PagedListAdapter`.

Here's our transform function.

```
List<TransformedTodo> transform(Todo todo)
```

Note, it is possible to transform 1 `Todo`, to 1 or many `TransformedTodo`.

My initial planned workflow is

1. Dao is returning `DataSource.Factory<Integer, Todo>`
2. Use `DataSource.Factory.mapByPage`, to transform `DataSource.Factory<Integer, Todo>` to `DataSource.Factory<Integer, TransformedTodo>`
3. Use `LivePagedListBuilder` to turn `DataSource.Factory<Integer, TransformedTodo>` into `LiveData<PagedList<TransformedTodo>>`
4. Observe `LiveData<PagedList<TransformedTodo>>`, and use `submitList` to pass `PagedList<TransformedTodo>` to `PagedListAdapter<TransformedTodo, TodoAdapter.ViewHolder>`

---

The tricky part is step 2.

If the transform function, is returning output `List<TransformedTodo>` where its size is different from input `List<Todo>`, exception will be thrown.

```
todosDataSourceFactory.mapByPage(new Function<List<Todo>, List<TransformedTodo>>() {
    @Override
    public List<TransformedTodo> apply(List<Todo> input) {
        // Exception will be thrown if we are returning a List where its size is different from input.
    }
});
```

The thrown exception is something which looks like

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid Function
>   com.yocto.wetodo.repository.TodoRepository$1@17b6f1b changed return
>   size. This is not supported.

Here's why

```
// androidx.paging.DataSource

static <A, B> List<B> convert(Function<List<A>, List<B>> function, List<A> source) {
    List<B> dest = function.apply(source);
    if (dest.size() != source.size()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Invalid Function " + function
                + " changed return size. This is not supported.");
    }
    return dest;
}
```

---

Seem like a limitation in paging library. Is there a way, to transform a `PagedList` to another `PagedList` with different size?

---

Reference links :

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142890117

[How to use AAC paging library with list size different than list size returned by Room database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52407806/how-to-use-aac-paging-library-with-list-size-different-than-list-size-returned-b)

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**

I have created a [library](https://github.com/Sarquella/MutableDataSource) to allow *Paging Library*'s DataSources page mutation.

---

The problem here is that *Paging Library* `mapByPage` is considered to return the same number of items as the input ones. To be able to return different number of items than the input, a custom *mutating* function would be required.

Another important thing to note before proceeding, specially when working with *Room*, is that the `DataSource.Factory<Key, Value>` will in fact end up generating a `PositionalDataSource`. Unlike `ItemKeyedDataSource` and `PageKeyedDataSource`, it requires that the resulting page items respect the defined *pageSize*. So, even if we create a `mapByPage`-like function to allow the mutation of its items, accepting different returned list size, it would still cause problems when working with a `PositionalDataSource` as it does not allow this list size modification.

A solution that could solve the problem would be to wrap the `PositionalDataSource` inside another of the two resting DataSources types, which allow to work with non-fixed page size, and make it behave as if it would actually be a `PositionalDataSource`.

Once we have a non-fixed page size compatible "`PositionalDataSource`", we can then add the *mapByPage*-like mutating function.

I have actually created a simple [MutableDataSource](https://github.com/Sarquella/MutableDataSource) library which does exactly that. It wraps the `PositionalDataSource` inside an equally behaving `PageKeyedDataSource`. Then, a `mutateByPage` function can be applied, allowing to change the resulting items, even changing the list size or item type. Additionally, I have also added support for mutating the `ItemKeyedDataSource` and `PageKeyedDataSource`.

Please, keep in mind this library could still contain bugs, so feel free to report any issue or to contribute.